# Node API gives timeout

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

For some reason the api that gets data from a Postgres database table doesnt return anything and timeouts. "errorMessage": "[504] - Lambda timeout." (Testing the get call on my browser).

My handler.js file:

```
const db = require('./db_connect');

module.exports.getAllUsers = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  db.getAll('public.user_roles')
    .then(res => {
      return callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(res)
      })
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      return callback(null, {
        statusCode: e.statusCode || 500,
        body: 'Error: Could not find Users: ' + e
      })
    })
};
```

my db_connect file:

```
const PgConnection = require('postgresql-easy');
const dbConfig = require('./config/db');
const pg = new PgConnection(dbConfig);
module.exports = pg;
```

my serverless.yml file:

```
service: aws-node-express-api-project
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 120
  region: ap-south-1

functions:        
  getAllUsers:
    handler: handler.getAllUsers
    events:
      - http:
          path: users
          method: get
          cors: true
          async: true
   
            
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

Comment: How long does the getAll call take? Is it longer than 120 seconds?

Comment: Not at all. There is just 1 record in table. In pgAdmin it takes few seconds. The getAll just keeps running and does not return anything. there is no error as well.

Comment: One Thing I Noticed is that everyday when i connect to my AWS RDS DB it gives timeout. I followed that article and allowed inbound access to my IP. I was able to successfully connect to my DB from pgAdmin. today again when i enter the password it shows timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's probably a network setup issue. If your Lambda function is public, then you'll need to allow public connections to your DB, unless you can narrow down [the IPs Lambda uses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) (you can't, really). If it's part of a VPC, then you'll need to ensure that your security groups and ACLs allow access.

One way to brute force test out whether this is the issue is to temporarily allow all public access to your DB and see if the Lambda function works. If so, then do the above and limit access to the DB from your Lambda function, most likely by [VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/foundation-networking.html).